# VBA fills microsoft form but when submited all fields are blanks

Tags: vba, forms, internet-explorer

This is part of my code:

```
For Each itm In IE.document.all
If itm = "[object HTMLInputElement]" Then
n = n + 1
var_dados = Empty
itm.Focus
itm.Click
Select Case n
Case 1
    var_dados = Worksheets("Rosto").Range("d8")
Case 3
    var_dados = Worksheets("Rosto").Range("d9")
'code here
itm.value = var_dados
```

And the data goes to the form, we see it there but when the form is submited and you go to see it, all fields are blank. What i´m doing rong?

Comment: What is the behavior without using VBA in IE? Will the fields go blank after submitting? Besides, we can't tell if there's anything wrong without the website you're operating. If possible, please provide the url of the website. If you can't provide the link, please provide related Html&JavaScript code which can **reproduce** the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i got a workaround

After this:

```
itm.value = var_dados
```

I used:

```
itm.Focus
itm.Click
```

Them used senkeys. The sendkeys needed to be some kind of text, case return or enter didn't worked.

And it worked